# Where in my WPF Style do i Put <Border CornerRadius="8">

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

Ive created a button style that works fine, but now I want to add rounded corners and i can't for the life of me figure out where to put the XAML. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <Rectangle.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
                        </Rectangle.Effect>
                    </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" TargetName="rectangle"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="rectangle">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="contentPresenter">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="rectangle">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You don't have an element in your template to even support it at this point. You have a `Rectangle` which you can hard set a `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` to 8 to simulate the same effect.

Comment: Set the RadiusX and RadiusY properties of the Rectangle.

Comment: Perfect! I was so centered on the border I forgot all about using the Radius. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know how to bind the property to the template so you can set it at the instance if you need it different in some place, can show you how to do that also if ya like.

Comment: @ Chris W. Thanks Chris but I'm ok there.

Comment: @ChrisW. , Jimdel, one of you should post this as an answer. Site guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Chris W's answer...

> You don't have an element in your template to even support it at this point. You have a Rectangle which you can hard set a RadiusX and RadiusY to 8 to simulate the same effect.